# Variable scope and Try Catch in python

Tags: python, variables, try-catch, scope, python-imaging-library

```
import Image
import os
for dirname, dirs, files in os.walk("."):
    for filename in files:
        try:
            im = Image.open(os.path.join(dirname,filename))
        except IOError:
            print "error opening file :: "  + os.path.join(dirname,filename)
        print im.size
```

Here I'm trying to print the size of all the files in a directory (and sub). But I know `im` is outside the scope when in the line `im.size`. But how else do I do it without using `else` or `finally` blocks.

The following error is shown:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "batch.py", line 13, in <module>
    print im.size
NameError: name 'im' is not defined
```

Comment: `im`'s scope is *not* limited to the `try` block; this is not C++.

Comment: @cdhowie: in that case, why the above error?

Comment: The error is shown because the variable `im` is not defined successfully if the `Image.open` fails hence it not existing when you try and access the `.size` attribute.

Comment: Because your `except` block "falls through" to the below code.  If an exception is thrown on the first iteration of the `for` loop, `im` will not yet have been assigned to and therefore will not exist.  You need to add `continue` so that the error is handled by repeating the loop on the next item.

Comment: Or just put `im.size` just after its assignment in the `try` block.

Comment: Trick I use for this... I catch for all the errors I can through `except` and then use the `else` clause of the try block to handle any final stuff like logging messages or defined-but-not-right checks; anything where a variable I'm declaring in `try` is needed.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

What's wrong with the "else" clause ?

```
for filename in files:
    try:
        im = Image.open(os.path.join(dirname,filename))
    except IOError, e:
        print "error opening file :: %s : %s" % (os.path.join(dirname,filename), e)
    else:
        print im.size
```

Now since you're in a loop, you can also use a "continue" statement:

```
for filename in files:
    try:
        im = Image.open(os.path.join(dirname,filename))
    except IOError, e:
        print "error opening file :: %s : %s" % (os.path.join(dirname,filename), e)
        continue

    print im.size
```

Answer (score 4):

If you can't open the file as an image, and only want to work on valid images, then include a [`continue`](http://docs.python.org/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-continue-statement) statement in your except block which will take you to the next iteration of your `for` loop.

```
try:
    im = Image.open(os.path.join(dirname, filename))
except IOError:
    print 'error opening file :: ' + os.path.join(dirname, filename)
    continue
```

Comment: tats not my question. but i gotta tell u, it works even without the `continue` statement.

Comment: @ShahalTharique Your question is flawed, because you assume that `im`'s scope is limited to the `try` block, when in fact it is not.

Comment: The `continue` is there so that if you have not successfully opened the image it will continue on to the next file in your for loop as you will not have an object called `im` created and therefore will not have access to its attributes and methods.

Answer (score 3):

```
import Image
import os
for dirname,dirs,files in os.walk("."):
    for filename in files:
        try:
            im = Image.open(os.path.join(dirname,filename))
            print im.size
        except IOError:
            print "error opening file :: "  + os.path.join(dirname,filename)
```

Also, no `;` in Python.

Comment: i want to code further, but i dont want it inside the try block. any ideas?

Comment: @ShahalTharique The problem is that your `except` block does not branch somewhere, so it executes and then the `print` statement does.  Since the exception was thrown, `im` was never assigned to.  You need to handle the error by going to the next item (`continue`) or by leaving the `for` loop (`break`).

Comment: -1 because writing more than the minimal amount of code inside a `try` can mask bugs.