# Try function not running correctly

Tags: python, python-3.x, try-catch

```
try:
    left_break = signs_pos[dave - 1]
except IndexError:
    left_error = True

try:
    right_break = signs_pos[dave + 1]
except IndexError:
    right_error = True

if left_error == True:
    current_cal = user_input[:right_break]
elif right_error == True:
    current_cal = user_input[left_break:]
else:
    current_cal = user_input[left_break:right_break]
```

I've only started looking at try functions and I need some help with this. What I would like to happen is that if when it tries to find left_break and it gives an error it will set left_error to be true. But if it does not give an error left_break will be set properly.

When the code runs and either right or left does not give an error it does not set left_break or right_break properly.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Max\Desktop\MaxsCal.py", line 170, in <module>
    current_cal = user_input[:right_break]
NameError: name 'right_break' is not defined
```

This is the error I get without the try function.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Max\Desktop\MaxsCal.py", line 157, in <module>
    right_break = signs_pos[dave + 1]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Both right_error and left_error will not be true.

Comment: It is a `NameError` not an `IndexError`

Comment: Your code doesn't handle the situation where both `try` statements execute the `except` part. Do you have the `left_break` and `right_break` variables defined `False` before this part of the code?

Comment: This might be because both `left_error` and `right_error` are `True` when none of the `try` blocks execute therefore the first `if` statement is evaluated and finds that `right_break` hasn't been created.

Comment: Ive edited with the error that it is trying

Comment: BTW, when `signs_pos[dave-1]` causes an `IndexError`, `signs_pos[dave+1]` surely will cause one as well. And if `dave` is `0`, it will be `signs_pos[-1]` which is the last item of that list and not going to cause an error.

Answer (score 3):

The reason why this is happening, is that because you are trying to assign *something* to a variable inside a try/except, it will not actually exist if you raised an exception.

Here is a simple example to clarify this:

```
try:
    x = 6 / 0
except ZeroDivisionError:
    print('this failed')
print(x)

>>> print(x)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'x' is not defined
```

Now, to remedy this and you are looking to actually use the variable even if it fails in the try/except, you want to declare it before you are calling the *thing* that might fail.

```
x = 0
try:
    x = 6 / 0
except ZeroDivisionError:
    print('this failed')
print(x)

>>> print(x)
>>> 0
```

Or even inside your try works, but before what you are calling:

```
try:
    x = 0
    x = 6 / 0
except ZeroDivisionError:
    print('this failed')
print(x)

>>> print(x)
>>> 0
```

As mentioned to me in the comments, you could also set a default in your `except`:

```
try:
    x = 6 / 0
except ZeroDivisionError:
    print('this failed')
    x = 0
print(x)

>>> print(x)
>>> 0
```

Comment: You could also give a default in the except

Comment: @PadraicCunningham That is true! Good call. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`left_break` and `right_break` are only available within the scope of the `try` block. You can either define them before the `try`/`except` block or add an `else` block to the exception, as discussed in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11185873/variable-scope-and-try-catch-in-python).

Answer (score 0):

Your error is coming from the fact that the variable is out of scope. Right break is only in scope within the try block, change it to

```
right_break = None
try:
    right_break = signs_pos[dave + 1]
except IndexError:
    right_error = True
```